# Printing keys as many times as it's value while exporting file

Tags: python, function, export

I'm trying to export to a CSV file, keys from the dictionary, and I want each key to be written as many times as his value. I want my output to be

`['battleaxe', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'gold coin']`

but instead I'm getting

`['battleaxe', 'daggerdaggerdagger', 'gold coin']`

My code:

```
def export_inventory(inventory, filename="export_inventory.csv"):
    with open(filename, "w") as csvfile:
        new = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
new.writerow((k*v for (k,v) in inventory.items()))
```

Test function:

```
def test_export_inventory(self):
    export_inventory({'dagger': 3, 'gold coin': 1, "battleaxe": 1},
                     "test_inventory_export.csv")

    with open("test_inventory_export.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
        expected = ["dagger", "gold coin", "battleaxe", "dagger", "dagger"]
        expected.sort()
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            row.sort()
            self.assertListEqual(expected, row)
```

Comment: Since the code is only 4 lines don't put gist just copy the code here.

Comment: what error u got from Test function

Comment: AssertionError: Lists differ: ['battleaxe', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'gold coin'] != []

First list contains 5 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
'battleaxe'

- ['battleaxe', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'gold coin']
+ []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because k*v will replicate the string v times e.g: o*3 gives use ooo.

```
def export_inventory(inventory, filename="export_inventory.csv"):
        l = []
        with open(filename, "w") as csvfile:
            new = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for key,value in inventory.items():
                l+=[key for _ in range(value)]
            new.writerow(l)
```

Comment: Thank you, but test checks only "dagger", "dagger","dagger" now, and not including the rest.

Comment: Yeah, you're sorry. I was saving the values as
dagger, dagger, dagger
gold coin
battleaxe

updated it now

Comment: No problem, but I still get error message: AssertionError: Lists differ: ['battleaxe', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'gold coin'] != []

First list contains 5 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
'battleaxe'

- ['battleaxe', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'gold coin']
+ []

Comment: weird I ran your code didn't have any problems.
https://gist.github.com/vedantshetty/7f9300a0fce2b5f099a34c5a64cc126a

Answer (score 1):

```
new.writerow((k for k,v in inventory.items() for _ in range(v)))
```

k*v is just string multiplication; 'a'*3 # aaaa

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

As we don't know the contents of the CSV, I am assuming a structure similar to the dict below based on your desired ouput.

```
weapons = {'battleaxe': 1, 'dagger': 3, 'gold coin': 1}

result = []

for item, times in weapons.items():
  for t in range(times):
    result.append(item)
print (result)

# ['battleaxe', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'dagger', 'gold coin']
```

Note that in your code you are doing k*v, effectively multiplying the item string as many times as the item is present. In my suggested code, we are adding it to a list instead.

Comment: Thank you, I have added content now.